# How to Remove one child node from firebase with out deleting all child nodes

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to remove a child node from firebase on a button click but when I use .RemoveValue() it deletes all the child nodes not just one.

```
 LeaderClass leader = new LeaderClass((uploadCurrent.getName()).trim(),
                        (uploadCurrent.getCategory()).trim(),(Integer.toString(mCountLikes )));
                mDatabaseLike.removeValue();
```

The full code is below:

```
    //Count Likes functionality
    mDatabaseRef.child((uploadCurrent.getName())).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                //Counting likes in 'Likes' database by counting children
                mCountLikes = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                holder.mCountbtn.setText(Integer.toString(mCountLikes ) + " Likes" );


               LeaderClass leader = new LeaderClass((uploadCurrent.getName()).trim(),
                     (uploadCurrent.getCategory()).trim(),(Integer.toString(mCountLikes )));

              mDatabaseLike.push().setValue(leader);




            }
            else{
                holder.mCountbtn.setText("0 Likes");

                LeaderClass leader = new LeaderClass((uploadCurrent.getName()).trim(),
                        (uploadCurrent.getCategory()).trim(),(Integer.toString(mCountLikes )));
                mDatabaseLike.removeValue();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is my firebase structure:

```
CountLikes: {
   "-LXBQRbkiL3fZUnRedrB": {
      category: "Technology"
      name: "Project 467"
      vote: "1"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `removeValue` on a `DatabaseReference` Firebase removes all data at that reference. It looks like your `mDatabaseLike` points to `CountLikes`, so calling `mDatabaseLike.removeValue()` removes all data under that location.

To remove a single child node, you'll need to know the key of the like to remove, i.e. the `-LXBQRbkiL3fZUnRedrB` in the JSON you shared.

When you know that, removing just that one child node is as simple as:

```
mDatabaseLike.child("-LXBQRbkiL3fZUnRedrB").removeValue();
```